# Reflection getMethod without causing exceptions

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way in Java reflection to call getMethod or some other one that won't throw an exception if a method isn't found?  Maybe just return a null instead?

I'm doing a pass through an application to decrease expected exceptions and this seems like a possible candidate.

Comment: Sure, if you wrap the call in your own method, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: What's wrong with a `try-catch` block?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about this, but having expected exceptions feels like code smell.

Comment: IMHO exceptions are part of the language. Under your assumption, why do checked exceptions exist in first place?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the getMethods() and return `null` if you don't find a match.

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution and a cache.  Thanks.

Comment: The Reflection API uses its own SoftReferenced cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application needs, maybe appropriate to use [getMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29). It return an array of all defined methods in your class. You can that map returned methods by name, or use them as you like.
Note, however, that this could be slower than call getMethod() only on the method you need and eventually catch the exception. Some caching could help in this case.

Comment: @Peter: sorry for the really similar answer, just not reading your as writing mine...

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already read this [**article**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html), check it out.

The Android developer's site doesn't seem to have an issue with using a `try-catch` block to achieve this effect... I think you should be fine.

If compatibility across multiple SDKs is your main concern, you might be able to avoid reflection all together by wrapping your code in `if-else` blocks as follows:

```
if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```